Implementaion of hmax for directed unfolding of Petri nets
Can somebody please help me try to understand if my implmentation and assumptions are right? Unfortunately, I do not have any means to reproduce it.
I'm trying to implement a heuristic function hmax for directed unfolding of Petri nets from a paper here. TLDR; it estimates a value for the remaining distance from one marking (argument a in my function) to another marking (b)  based upon the definition given in the link. You do not need to know what a Mark or a Configuration is, just need to know how Petri nets work.
The paper uses 1 + min() in their definition but since I'm using cost-based directed unfolding, I use a cost_function too. Also, since the computation is cyclic, it might end up in a loop during recursion, hence I use an in_stack to keep track of calls. Whenever a loop is detected the function returns inf and since I use min over all the paths, the distance should be computed over non-looping paths. Another  addition from my side is in:
if len(possible_candidates) == 0:
   return 0

Not sure if this is a right assumption. I cannot explain why possible_candidates sometimes is 0.
            def compute_hmax(
                self,
                mark: frozenset[PetriNet.Place],
                target: Set[PetriNet.Place],
                cost_function,
            ):
                if len(mark) == 0:
                    self.local_configuration.hmax = 0
                else:
                    in_stack = (
                        dict()
                    )  # stack to detect visited nodes in the search to detect cycles
                    d = self.hmax(mark, frozenset(target), in_stack, cost_function)
                    self.local_configuration.hmax = d

            @cached(
                cache={},
                key=lambda self, a, b, in_stack, cost_function: hashkey((a, b)),
            )
            def hmax(
                self,
                a: frozenset[PetriNet.Place],
                b: frozenset[PetriNet.Place],
                in_stack,
                cost_function,
            ):
                if b.issubset(a):
                    return 0

                elif len(b) == 1:
                    q = list(b)[0]

                    if q in in_stack:
                        return float("inf")  # cycle detected

                    in_stack[q] = True

                    pre_trans = set(map(lambda arc: arc.source, q.in_arcs))

                    possible_candidates = list(
                        map(
                            lambda t: (
                                t,
                                self.hmax(
                                    a, frozenset(t.preset), in_stack, cost_function
                                ),
                            ),
                            pre_trans,
                        )
                    )

                    in_stack.pop(q)

                    if len(possible_candidates) == 0:
                        return 0

                    min_d_tup = min(possible_candidates, key=lambda t: t[1] + cost_function[t[0]])

                    return cost_function[min_d_tup[0]] + min_d_tup[1]

                else:
                    return max(
                        list(
                            map(
                                lambda t: self.hmax(
                                    a, frozenset({t}), in_stack, cost_function
                                ),
                                b,
                            )
                        )
                    )


Hi, I am not quite sure what your question is.
I am not well versed in python, but at a first glance the implementation seems ok. Do you have any indication that it is wrong? Do you have an example input for which it does not work as expected?
A minor nitpick: you should call the local variable in the else lambda p instead of t.

possible_candidaates can be zero in two cases: your net contains places with an empty pre-fix, or your net contains transitions with an empty pre-fix. If you have a net with places with an empty pre-fix the cost of marking them should be infinite. if they are already marked in M (a), then your if catches them, but if they are not marked they can never be marked and are unreachable. The oposite is true if you have transitions with an empty pre-fix (they can always fire), but the paper mentions one-safe nets, so this should never happen if your nets are one-safe.

What might be problematic is sending your in_stack into the recurrsive calls. I did not check if it is really the case, but it feels like parallel checks should be tracked with stacks that are independant of each other, as you might have some state information leaking from one computation to the other without intending it. You should try to run your code through a debugger and see if this works as intended. Perhaps it might be desirable to pass copies of the stack into the recurrsive calls?

thanks for the pointers. I couldn't find an instance where the hmax values are wrong. But for large instances for which the unfolding is wide,  heuristics don't seem to guide my search at all. In fact, for this eg, I have more nodes in my unfolding than without heuristics.

maybe there's something else wrong, I'm still debugging. From this question, I just wanted to get a second opinion, just in case I understood/implemented it wrong :/

@Minop also noticed that my final hmax value is inf for a few instances. That shouldn't have happened. :/

if you are getting inf as a result of the final hmax it might explain why this heuristic does not guide the search correctly, as it might be steering your search away from paths that would be taken by a simpler search. I would try figuring out why you get the wrong result. Maybe try to find a small example where it happens.

I found an example. The inf is because of @cached that I'm using. hmax is using results from different paths when it detected a loop. But, without cached, my algorithm is so damn slow. :'( I'm gonna cry. Do you know of any other heuristics I could use? or maybe change this in a way that it still underestimates without having to do away with caching?

Never mind, I think I found a good one to use. it's giving me no surprises so far o.o
But thanks anyway :)
